# Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'id' in package

Tags: android

I am getting this error for the menu item I have added for the toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera_iris_white_36dp"
        android:id="@+id/video_camera"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_camera_label"></item>
</menu>
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue ? Here are the build errors

```
> Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'id' in package
> 'com.google.rabbit'
> 
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> 'C:\Users\sagar_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe''
> finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: try to invalid catch/restart @Savita

Comment: try this `app:showAsAction="always" `

Comment: use `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` as root

Comment: @Blackbelt How to use it as root?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it didn't work.

Comment: replace your `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` with `<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

Comment: @Savita follow #Blackbelt sir tips

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks it worked :)

Comment: you are welcome. I posted it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'id' in package
>   'com.google.rabbit'

Accordingly to the compile time error, you have the wrong namespace in your xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

should be

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Rectify your **Root** section with proper **Tag**

**Finally**

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Sync** .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera_iris_white_36dp"
        android:id="@+id/video_camera"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/menu_camera_label"></item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.sixmod.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/titlename"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/video_camera"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera_iris_white_36dp"

    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/menu_camera_label"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved such issue with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```